# Where can I get a list of kwargs for the print function in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, keyword-argument

I only know of one kwarg for the print function and that's `end=`, are there others?

I looked in the documentation here:

https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/inputoutput.html

But it doesn't seem to be real comprehensive regarding the `kwarg`s for `print()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) what you are looking for?

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)